# Weight limit for my bicycle

Tags: mountain-bike, heavy, clydesdale

i bought my mountain bike litterally an hour ago but i feel im a bit to heavy for the bicycle.
I weigh 120kg (backpack weight included).
Its a Avalanche Reflex 29er 2018 model with a size 20 frame.
Am i just being paranoid?
If its the wrong size then ill just have to do an exchange so any help ASAP will be appreciated as it will be my transport to, and from work

Comment: If you are using it as a commuter and that weight then a touring bike designed for weight might have been a better choice.

Comment: Why do you feel like you're too heavy? How much of the weight is the backpack? If it's more than a few kg then transferring some or all of this weight to the frame will make the ride feel nicer.

Comment: Their web site doesn't give much info, but I see that they're 36-spoke wheels, which should be plenty strong.  The weak point would likely be the front shocks.  Can't say anything about size and fit -- that's pretty personal.

Comment: Check with the shop where you bought the bike.  They should have sold you a bike suitable for your weight.

Comment: Heman - This has been flagged as off-topic because its completely personal to you, and has no practical relevance to anyone else.  SE is about building long-term useful collections of practical problems and validated answers, whereas this sounds like a bad shopping decision on your part or a salesperson has sold you something that is wrong for you.

Answer (score 8):

120 KG is 265 lbs. You might want to contact the manufacturer to get an exact number on the recommended maximum rider weight. Other bikes by high end manufacturers usually are around 250-300 lbs. Usually aluminum/alloy frames are around 300 lbs while carbon frames are around 250 lbs. This isn't because carbon is weaker, but rather because carbon bikes are designed with a different kind of rider in mind.  Double check with the manufacturer, but you are most likely fine. You may have problems with bent spokes if you are rough on the bike, but the frame should be fine.

Comment: Agreed, most of my companies bike are listed as 250lbs max, however this is a legal/lawyer number and they can likely hold quite a bit more without too much issue, like Kibbee said you may pop or bend spokes but for commuting should be okay.

Answer (score 2):

Most of the times the frames aren't the biggest issue with weight. What's mostly limiting are the wheels. Especially if theses are cheaper 29" wheels you should check the manufacturer for a weight restriction.

But in the end it depends on what you mostly ride with the bike. If it is mostly commuting you should be fine.
As said before the front shock could also become a problem.

Answer (score 2):

tl;dr - You have a cheaply made bike which is why it's squirrelly, I’d return it and get  a quality used bike.

Your bike has an MSRP of ZAR3575 which equates to around US$285 or €240. Assuming that it’s sold for less than 80% of MSRP that means it’s a 200 eurodollar bike.

[image: Avalanche Reflex 29er 2018]
That’s firmly [BSO or flat pack bicycle territory](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bso?mixed=1).

The squirreliness that you’re feeling could simply be that the bike is poorly built or assembled. Most BSOs are sold out of mass market retailers (supermarkets, department stores) and the minimum wage clerk who assembled it out of a flat pack might not know anything about chain alignment or proper torque values. But to be honest, it’s often impossible to properly assemble a BSO as the manufacturing quality is so low and the materials used so suspect.

If your budget is sub-200 Eurodollars, you would do much better getting a used, brand name bike - preferably from a bike shop that has refurbished it.

Now, as other answers attest, most bikes have a 100-150kg or so maximum weight limit. However on quality MTBs, that weight limit is calculated assuming the rider is going to be doing jumps and otherwise bashing the bike hard. For gentle commuting, even at your weight you wouldn’t be putting the bike through the types of stress a 75kg semipro rider would be putting on it riding off-road.